# Python: How to prepend the string 'ub' to every pronounced vowel in a string?

Tags: python, regex, string, nlp

**Example**: Speak -> Spubeak, [more info here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubbi_dubbi)

Don't give me a solution, but point me in the right direction or tell which which python library I could use? I am thinking of regex since I have to find a vowel, but then which method could I use to insert 'ub' in front of a vowel?

Comment: First you’ll need a proper dictionary with pronunciations.  Then you’ll have to realize that *little*, *acre*, *nth*, and *psst* are all words that sport non-traditional vowels, since the *e* in *little* and *acre* is silent, but those have two sylables, proving that *l* and *r* are vowels in those words. Of course *m* is a vowel in the two-syllable word *rhythm*. Similarly *nth* and *psst* obviously have *n* and *s* acting as vowels in those two one-syllable words. How many syllables do *fire* and *fiery* have? How many vowels does *queue* have in it? *Y* is a vowel in *spy* but not in *yes*.

Comment: This is not a good question for StackOverflow because it is about subject matter knowledge of locale-specific linguistics that has nothing to do with programming, computer science, or mathematics.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is more complex then just a simple regex [e.g.,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubbi_dubbi)

```
"Hi, how are you?" → "Hubi, hubow ubare yubou?"
```

Simple regex won't catch that `e` is not pronounced in `are`.

You need a library that provides a pronunciation dictionary such as `nltk.corpus.cmudict`:

```
from nltk.corpus import cmudict # $ pip install nltk
# $ python -c "import nltk; nltk.download('cmudict')"

def spubeak(word, pronunciations=cmudict.dict()):
    istitle = word.istitle() # remember, to preserve titlecase
    w = word.lower() #note: ignore Unicode case-folding
    for syllables in pronunciations.get(w, []):
        parts = []
        for syl in syllables:
            if syl[:1] == syl[1:2]:
                syl = syl[1:] # remove duplicate
            isvowel = syl[-1].isdigit()
            # pronounce the word
            parts.append('ub'+syl[:-1] if isvowel else syl)
        result = ''.join(map(str.lower, parts))
        return result.title() if istitle else result
    return word # word not found in the dictionary
```

Example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re

sent = "Hi, how are you?"
subent = " ".join(["".join(map(spubeak, re.split("(\W+)", nonblank)))
                   for nonblank in sent.split()])
print('"{}" → "{}"'.format(sent, subent))
```

#### Output

```
"Hi, how are you?" → "Hubay, hubaw ubar yubuw?"
```

Note: It is different from the first example: each word is replaced with its syllables.

Comment: I’ve yet to see any approach to this that properly identifies *spY, AcRe, fIRe, fIeRY, lIttLe, rhYthM, queUe, Nth, pSst, yEarlY*, but those are certainly good things to test it with.

Comment: You'd have to start re-spelling them. spy -> spubai, acre -> ubay-cubre, firey -> fuba-iubur-ubee

Answer (score 3):

You can use regular expressions for substitutions. See [`re.sub`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.sub).

Example:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'(e)', r'ub\1', 'speak')
'spubeak'
```

You will need to read the documentation for regex groups and so on. You will also need to figure out how to match different vowels instead of just the one in the example.

For some great ideas (and code) for using regular expressions in Python for a pronunciation dictionary, take a look at this link, which is one of the design pages for the [Cainteoir](http://rhdunn.github.com/cainteoir/) project: http://rhdunn.github.com/cainteoir/rules.html

Cainteoir's text-to-speech rule engine design (which is not fully implemented yet) uses regular expressions. See also [Pronunciation Dictionaries and Regexes](http://rhdunn.github.com/cainteoir/tts/2011/07/07/pronunciation-dictionaries-and-regexes.html), another article by the Cainteoir author.

Comment: -1: Regexes will not be able to distinguish pronounced vowels from silent ones.

Comment: @Platinum First of all, the OP specifically asked for a non-solution, just a way to substitute in front of a vowel. Second, you can absolutely write a regular expression which distinguishes pronounced vowels from silent ones. Do you really think a text-to-speech synthesizer can't be implemented using regular expressions? If you can't write a regular expression to identify a spoken vowel, how do YOU parse it as a person?

Comment: @Platinum Here's a link for you which describes how to generate a pronunciation dictionary using regular expressions: http://rhdunn.github.com/cainteoir/rules.html

Comment: No, you're not reading the question title. *Python: How to prepend the string 'ub' to every **pronounced** vowel in a string* (emphasis mine).

Comment: @Platinum You should also read that the OP wrote "Don't give me a solution, but point me in the right direction". That's part of the question...

Comment: +1 for the link to Cainteoir project (the part with grapheme to phoneme rules)

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions are really the best route. If you are unsure of how to proceed, check how capturing groups work, and how you can include them in your substitutions.

Comment: -1: Regexes will not be able to distinguish pronounced vowels from silent ones.

Comment: Well, I'm not a native english speaker, so I can't argue with that... The OP asked for pointers to help him handle the task, not an outright solution, and I suggested some features of regexes he might not be aware of. But I never claimed a single regex replace would do the whole trick.

Comment: In fairness, if the OP had a way to identify pronouced vowels, one which modified the string to mark those vowels, then regex substitution could possibly do the appropriate string substitution. Then again, the aforementioned "marking" could come in the form of adding `ub`, rendering the regex part unnecessary. Worse, the original problem remains in that case.