# Matching Patterns with Text in Between

Tags: python, regex, substitution

In quantitative verse (like what's used in Greek and Latin poetry), lines are split into parts called spondees and dactyls. A dactyl is a long vowel (like ā) followed by two short vowels, while a spondee is two long vowels.

My goal is to automate the splitting of lines into spondees and dactyls in Python.

Given a line like

```
ārma virūmqe canō
```

I'm trying to get the output

```
arma vi / rūmque ca / nō
```

I've been thinking that using a regex to find either the pattern (long,short,short), or (long,long) would be a good idea, but I can't seem to figure out how to deal with the fact that these vowels are rarely going to be consecutive, and that the number of consonants between them will vary every time.

Is there a way to look for specific characters with an arbitrary number of other, irrelevant characters between them, using a regex? If not, is there another, relatively elegant way to achieve the same goal?

**Edit:**

If you need more examples [@Junuxx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1404505/junuxx) pointed out a great site. [Here's](http://www.skidmore.edu/classics/courses/1998fall/cl202/resource/meter/figi.JPG) a link to a picture of the scansion of the first 7 lines of the Aeneid, from which I got the example above. Every time that there are just two vowels in a segment, it's a spondee. If there are three, it's a dactyl. Ignore the bolded lines, as they just indicate the third division in a line.

**Edit II:**

Looks like I made a typo in my example. I wrote "virumqe", when, in reality, the line is "virumque". In Latin, (ae,au,ei,eu,oe) are dipthongs, and are treated as one vowel. I suppose, then, that I must amend my question to ask if it's possible to deal with those as well.

Comment: Can you add a few more examples, especially for the spondee?

Comment: I agree with @poke. Some more examples would be nice. I'm greek and I didn't understand a thing :)

Comment: Interesting, according to [**this**](http://www.skidmore.edu/classics/courses/1998fall/cl202/resource/meter/metintro.html), the example should be divided `arma / vi rumque / ca no`

Comment: That's true, but that version isn't complete. "ue" is a dipthong, which means that it's counted as one vowel. Hence, the vowels are "i","u", and "ue". A little further down that page, the author explains more, and the final, big, version has it as I do.

Comment: if splitting on parts depends on pronunciation (e.g., spY) then see related question: [Python: How to prepend the string 'ub' to every pronounced vowel in a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9505714/4279)

Comment: It doesn't. For a pronunciation based replacement, you need a corpus of pronunciations, whereas, with this, you just need to count vowels and indicate whenever a patterns has been fulfilled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code below works on your example, however, the regex is rather long since there's no concise way to match consonants.

Breakdown of the regex for a dactyl:

```
 [^āēīōūaeiou]*  # 0 or more consonants
 [āēīōū]         # a long vowel
 [^āēīōūaeiou]*  # 0 or more consonants
 [aeiou]         # a short vowel
 [^āēīōūaeiou]*  # 0 or more consonants
 [aeiou]         # a short vowel 
 [^āēīōūaeiou]*? # 0 or more consonants, but as few as possible
```

Code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import re
s = u"ārma virūmqe canō"
# Long vowels: āēīōū

m = re.findall(u'([^āēīōūaeiou]*[āēīōū][^āēīōūaeiou]*' # Dactyls
               u'[aeiou][^āēīōūaeiou]*[aeiou][^āēīōūaeiou]*?'
               u'|'
               u'[^āēīōūaeiou]*[āēīōū][^āēīōūaeiou]*?'  # Spondees
               u'[āēīōū]?[^āēīōūaeiou]*'
               u'|'
               u'[\w\s]*)', s)                         # Catch all leftovers

try:
    print ' / '.join(m)
except:
    print 'no match'
```

Output:

```
ārma vi / rūmqe ca / nō
```

Comment: You could match everything *except* vowels.

Comment: Thanks a ton! I think I'm finally starting to understand the power of regexes.  I'm sorry, though, but I made a typo in my original post, a typo that I only caught because of your comment about the alternate scansion. Thing is, the line has "ue" in it, which is a dipthong (The Latin dipthongs are "ae,au,ei,eu,oe"). Dipthongs are counted as only one vowel (apparently in my mind, as well), and my question, then, is how one might go about treating those as such. Is there a way to incorporate that in? Or do I have to do something external to the regex?

Comment: @Tutleman: That should be easy to solve with a couple of `+`es and `*`s in the right places, I think. How does it work in situations with 3 or 4 vowels? (e.g. quaestor, quiae)

Comment: @Junuxx Awesome! Thanks again! For quaestor, "ua" isn't a dipthong (which, by the way, are long), but "ae" is, so "u" would be short, and "ae" would be long. It would come out to be "quāēstor". For quiae, neither "ui" nor "ia" is a dipthong, so "u" would be one vowel, "i" would be one vowel, and "āē" would be one vowel.