# In python, how do I find the vowels in a word?

Tags: python

I am trying to make an up language translator. Simple task for me in python. Or so i thought. If you are unaware, up language is when you take a word and say it while adding up before every vowel. for example, Andrew would be Upandrupew. I am trying to find out how find all of the vowels in a user submitted word, and put up before them. Is there a way to cut up a word before all vowels. so excellent would be exc ell ent? thanks.

Comment: How do want to replace: "Hi, how are you?" (note: `e` in `are` is not pronounced). See [Python: How to prepend the string 'ub' to every pronounced vowel in a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9505714/4279)

Answer (score 8):

maybe

```
VOWELS = 'aeiou'
def up_it(word):
    letters = []
    for letter in word:
        if letter.lower() in VOWELS:
            letters.append('Up')
        letters.append(letter)
    return ''.join(letters)
```

can be simplified to

```
def up_it(word):
    return ''.join('up'+c if c.lower() in 'aeiou' else c for c in word)
```

Answer (score 6):

You could do that with a regex:

```
import re
a = "Hello World."
b = re.sub("(?i)([aeiou])", "up\\1", a)
```

The `(?i)` makes it case-insensitive. `\\1` refers to the character that was matched inside `([aeiou])`.

Comment: Add a + to capture a group of vowels, i.e. `re.sub("(?i)([aeiou]+)", "up\\1", a)`. Try your solution with a word like "beautiful" and you'll see why it's not ideal.

Comment: @jsdalton I'm not familiar with "up language", so I followed the letter of the spec in the OP's question. Your suggestion seems like it would look better though!

Comment: [more examples to consider](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9505714/python-how-to-prepend-the-string-ub-to-every-pronounced-vowel-in-a-string#comment12037522_9505714)

Answer (score 2):

```
''.join(['up' + v if v.lower() in 'aeiou' else v for v in phrase])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for vowel in [“a“,“e“,“i“,“o“,“u“]:
    Word = Word.replace(vowel,“up“+vowel)
print(Word)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
sentence = "whatever"
q = re.sub(r"([aieou])", r"up\1", sentence, flags=re.I)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']

def upped_word(word):
    output = ''
    for character in word:
        if character.lower() in vowels:
            output += "up"
        output += character
    return output
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one-liner for the entire problem

```
>>> "".join(('up' + x if x.upper() in 'AEIOU' else x for x in 'andrew'))
'upandrupew'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way of doing it.

```
wordList = list(string.lower())

wordList2 = []

for letter in wordList:
    if letter in 'aeiou':
        upLetter = "up" + letter
        wordList2.append(upLetter)
    else:
        wordList2.append(letter)

"".join(wordList2)
```

Create a list of letters (wordList), iterate through those letters and append it to a second list, which is joined at the end.

Returns:

```
10: 'upandrupew'
```

In one line:

```
"".join(list("up"+letter if letter in "aeiou" else letter for letter in list(string.lower())))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably go with RegExp but there are already many answers using it. My second choice is the map function, witch is better then iterate through every letter.

```
>>> vowels = 'aeiou'
>>> text = 'this is a test'
>>> ''.join(map(lambda x: 'up%s'%x if x in vowels else x, text))
'thupis upis upa tupest'
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def is_vowel(word):
    ''' Check if `word` is vowel, returns bool. '''
    # Split word in two equals parts
    if len(word) % 2 == 0:
        parts = [word[0:len(word)/2], word[len(word)/2:]]
    else:
        parts = [word[0:len(word)/2], word[(len(word)/2)+1:]]

    # Check if first part and reverse second part are same.
    if parts[0] == parts[1][::-1]:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a smart solution which helps you to count and find vowels in input string:

```
name = input("Name:- ")
counter = []
list(name)

for i in name:                 #It will check every alphabet in your string
    if i in ['a','e','i','o','u']:  # Math vowels to your string
        print(i,"  This is a vowel")
        counter.append(i)      # If he finds vowels then he adds that vowel in empty counter
    else:
        print(i)

print("\n")
print("Total no of words in your name ")
print(len(name))

print("Total no of vowels in your name ")
print(len(counter))
```