# Textblob cannot pluralize/singularize verbs correctly

Tags: python, nlp, textblob

I want to pluralize verbs in TextBlob, for example: introduces -> introduce.

```
from textblob.en.inflect import singularize, pluralize
from textblob import Word
Word('introduces').pluralize() # returns 'introducess'
pluralize(Word('introduces'), pos='VB') # returns 'introducess'
singularize(Word('introduce'), pos='VB') # returns 'introduce' instead of 'introduces'
pluralize(Word('was'), pos='VB') # returns 'wass'
```

It seems that it treats verbs as nouns. What I am doing wrong?

Is there any other libs that can do it correctly? 
I already tried [inflect](https://pypi.org/project/inflect/0.2.4/)
which can correctly pluralize verbs but not singularize.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31387905/converting-plural-to-singular-in-a-text-file-with-python check this