# Why some word that should have in nltk corpus missing?

Tags: python, nltk

i want to write the program to examine word by using nltk corpus but i don't know why some word that nltk should have but it not.

this is my code.

```
import nltk

word = "women"
words = set(nltk.corpus.words.words())
if word in words:
    print(word)
```

and the output is show nothing.

Comment: try  "woman" (as in: singular - not plural)

Comment: @Patrick Artner thank you for response, and how can i check if this is a word not only as in singular because i just want to clean junk word in my data.

Comment: You have to get the singular from the plural then - see f.e.[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31387905/converting-plural-to-singular-in-a-text-file-with-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31387905/converting-plural-to-singular-in-a-text-file-with-python) - you wont find a list that includes all words, singular and plural as well as re/inflected. Bring your word to the base-case and try it against curpus.words.words().

Comment: @PatrickArtner thank you very much :)