# Joining consonants and vowels in python

Tags: python, list, loops, grouping

I have already defined vowel in my script. I next want to be able to join consonants and vowels together,

for example:

if a consonant follows a vowel, I want to take that section of the word and group it together in a list.

If I have the word "house" I want to be able to have an output in a list like

```
['h', 'ous', 'e]
```

I Should first separate the word so that it is

```
['h', 'o', 'u', 's', 'e']
```

and then worry about adding them together, or what is the best approach?

I was thinking about using a while or for loop.

Comment: could you show us the code you have now?

Comment: Ok, then use which loops you feel  you are comfortable and do some coding. Do question if you face problem in your code, of course with  a code portion.

Comment: Are you open to using a regex solution?

Comment: do you consider `é` (U+0065 U+0301) to be a vowel? Should it be considered one or two characters in your application? Does pronunciation count? [Is there a vowel in `nth`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9505714/python-how-to-prepend-the-string-ub-to-every-pronounced-vowel-in-a-string#comment12037522_9505714)?

Answer (score 0):

I think this function does what you need:

```
vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
consonants = ['b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']

def group_vowels(string):
    output = []
    substring = ''
    # Loop through each character in the string
    for i, c in enumerate(string, start=1):
        # If it's a consonant, add it to the current substring
        # and then add the substring to the output list
        if c in consonants:
            substring = substring + c
            output.append(substring)
            substring = ''
        # If it's a vowel, add it to the current substring
        if c in vowels:
            substring = substring + c
            # If the word ends with vowels, add them to the output list
            if i == len(string): output.append(substring)
    return output

print group_vowels('house') # ['h', 'ous', 'e']
print group_vowels('ouagadougou') # ['ouag', 'ad', 'oug', 'ou']
```

As J.F. Sebastian commented, you might want to expand the `vowels` and `consonants` lists.

Comment: You are missing some output in your second example, last should be `ou`

Comment: You could also make the vowels and consonants sets for 0(1) lookups

Answer (score 0):

A few more examples would help, but the following approach seems to work with your current example for `house`:

```
print [g for g in re.split(r'([aeiou]+?[^aeiou]+?)', 'house', flags=re.I) if g]
```

This displays:

```
['h', 'ous', 'e']
```