# Baby talk function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to construct a function where the *input* is a normal sentence and the *output* is that sentence translated to "child language". Child language means to only say the first syllable in every word but saying it 3 times. 
So "hello world" would be "hehehe wowowo".

My idea is to first split the sentence into a list of words. Then for every word we should have a counter that starts at 0. If consonant the counter adds 0 - if vowel the counter adds 1. When the counter 1 one we stop, return the consonants and the vowel and go to the next word. But I am having trouble "accessing" going through every word in the list. How can I set my idea in to practice?

Comment: please post an attempt to what you are trying to do and some actual issues that have come up  so we can better help you out

Comment: in other words: show your code.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.  
StackOverflow is not a coding or tutorial service.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a 0-1 counter; that's called a Boolean flag.  When you find the vowel, just continue to the next step.

```
vowel_list = 'aeiou'
sentence = "hello world"

# split the sentence into a list of words.
word_list = sentence.split()
for word in word_list:
    # Find the minimal pronounceable prefix and print it 3 times
    # Find the first vowel
    for i in range(len(word)):
        if word[i] in vowel_list:
            # Grab the consonants and vowel, and stop
            syllable = word[:i+1]
            break
    # Report the syllable in triplicate
    print syllable*3
```

The output from this is

```
hehehe
wowowo
```

That should get you through the immediate questions.  You still get to cobble this into a function the way you described, and then put the individual baby words into a baby sentence.  I'll also leave it to you to handle problem cases, such as

```
each
school
rhythm
```

If this doesn't solve *anything* for you, then please edit the question with a clearer description.

Answer (score 1):

Here's baby talk generated based on [word pronunciations](http://www.speech.cs.cmu.edu/cgi-bin/cmudict) and written using [arpabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arpabet):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from nltk.corpus import cmudict  # $ pip install nltk
# >>> nltk.download('cmudict')

def baby_talk(word, repeat=3, phone_sep=u'\N{NO-BREAK SPACE}',
              pronunciations=cmudict.dict()):
    for phones in pronunciations.get(word.casefold(), []):
        for i, ph in enumerate(phones):
            if ph[-1] in '012':  # found vowel sound
                return phone_sep.join((phones[:i] + [ph[:-1]]) * repeat)
    return naive_baby_talk(word, repeat, phone_sep)  # no pronunciations


def naive_baby_talk(word, repeat, phone_sep, vowels="aeiouAEIOU"):
    i = None
    for i, char in enumerate(word, start=1):
        if char in vowels:
            break  # found vowel
    return phone_sep.join([word[:i]] * repeat)
```

Example:

```
import re

sentences = ["hello world",
             "Quiet European rhythms.",
             "My nth happy hour.",
             "Herb unit -- a dynasty heir."]
for sentence in sentences:
    sesese = " ".join(["".join(
        [w if i & 1 or not w else baby_talk(w)  # keep non-words as is
         for i, w in enumerate(re.split("(\W+)", non_whitespace))])
        for non_whitespace in sentence.split()])
    print(u'"{}" → "{}"'.format(sentence, sesese))
```

#### Output

```
"hello world" → "HH AH HH AH HH AH W ER W ER W ER"
"Quiet European rhythms." → "K W AY K W AY K W AY Y UH Y UH Y UH R IH R IH R IH."
"My nth happy hour." → "M AY M AY M AY EH EH EH HH AE HH AE HH AE AW AW AW."
"Herb unit -- a dynasty heir." → "ER ER ER Y UW Y UW Y UW -- AH AH AH D AY D AY D AY EH EH EH."
```

Note:

- `nth`, `hour`, `herb`, `heir` start with a vowel
- `European`, `unit` start with a consonant
- `y` in "rhythms", "dynasty" is a vowel

See:

- [Pig Latin Translator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22773826/4279)
- [Python: How to prepend the string 'ub' to every pronounced vowel in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9505714/4279)

Answer (score 0):

```
def end_at_vowel(string):
    vowels = ["a","e","i","o","u"] # A list of vowels
    letters = []
    for l in string:
        letters += l
        if l in vowels:
            break
    return "".join(letters)
def bbt(string):
    string = string.split() #Split the string into a list
    return " ".join([end_at_vowel(w) * 3 for w in string])
```

This should handle mostly what you described. Take a look at the comments and the two functions and see if you can decipher what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the few times I'd recommend regular expressions:

```
import re

FIRST_SYLLABLE = re.compile(r'.*?[aeiou]', re.IGNORECASE)

def baby_talk(sentence):
    words = []
    for word in sentence.split():
        match = FIRST_SYLLABLE.match(word)
        if match:
            words.append(match.group(0) * 3)
    return ' '.join(words)

print baby_talk('hello world')
```

Line by line:

```
import re

FIRST_SYLLABLE = re.compile(r'.*?[aeiou]', re.IGNORECASE)
```

This makes a compiled pattern that matches anything up to and including the first vowel.

```
def baby_talk(sentence):
    words = []
    for word in sentence.split():
        match = FIRST_SYLLABLE.match(word)
```

This attempts to match the word against our compiled pattern.

```
        if match:
            words.append(match.group(0) * 3)
```

If it works, `match.group(0)` contains the matching portion. Given 'hello', `match.group(0)` will be 'he'. Make three copies of it and add it to the output word list.

```
    return ' '.join(words)
```

Return the output word list joined together by spaces.

```
print baby_talk('hello world')
```